# How to keep one of the expansion panel always expanded in an accordion?

Tags: angular, accordion, expand, mat-expansion-panel

I'm having an accordion with 3 expansion panels. I want to keep at least one panel open always.
i.e, I don't want the user to close all the panels.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expanded] property available in mat-accordion.
Add the below code in the mat-expansion-panel tag

```
[expanded]="true"
```

Comment: It works only for the first time, my use case is, when the user collapses one panel, the next one should open up. One of the three should always be open.

Comment: For this case you can use [expanded]=some_variable for all three expansion panel, and add click event listener to the expansion panel and toggle the state.